# Vue 2 Composition API + Typescript - TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown' using provide/inject

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

I develop simple Laravel application using Vue.
I can't get rid of Typescript error `TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.` when accessing prop.

I have two Vue single file components:

**Parent:**

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, provide } from '@vue/composition-api';
import { AppConfig, appConfigKey } from './app-config';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.vue';

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    ChildComponent
  },
  setup() {
    const appConfig: AppConfig = {
      alias: 'foo',
      name: 'foo',
      shortName: 'foo',
      url: 'foo'
    };
    provide(appConfigKey, appConfig)
  }
})
</script>
```

**Child:**

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, inject } from '@vue/composition-api';
import { AppConfig, appConfigKey } from './app-config';

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const appConfig: AppConfig = inject(appConfigKey);
    console.log(appConfig.shortName); // TS error here
  }
})
</script>
```

In my app-config file I have:

```js
import { InjectionKey } from '@vue/composition-api';

export interface AppConfig {
  alias: string;
  name: string;
  shortName: string;
  url: string;
}

export const appConfigKey: InjectionKey<AppConfig> = Symbol('appConfig');
```

My tsconfig file:

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noImplicitReturns": false,
        "noImplicitThis": false,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "allowUnusedLabels": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["resources/assets/js/*"]
        },
        "lib": ["esnext", "dom"]
    }
}
```

ESLint doesn't complain, but webpack doesn't want to compile the code.
Please, can you help me figure it out? I am not experienced Typescript developer. I used to work with Vue Options API.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a different error (w/TypeScript 4.1.5):

> ```
> Type 'AppConfig | undefined' is not assignable to type 'AppConfig'. ts(2322)
> ```

...which points to this line:

> ```
> const appConfig: AppConfig = inject(appConfigKey);
>       ^^^^^^^^^
> ```

You don't need to type `appConfig` because it can already be inferred as `AppConfig | undefined`:

```js
const appConfig = inject(appConfigKey);
```

Since `appConfig` is possibly `undefined`, use [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) to reference its properties:

```js
console.log(appConfig?.shortName);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sure, type should be inferred from the injection, but I tried different approaches. I also tried optional chaining with no luck. Code above is one of many versions I tried. I guess it could be some problem with configuration.